# How can I close opened drivers during Selenium tests with TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, grid, hudson, testng

I have a Selenium project which runs fine on my local machine but has a problem when run by Hudson. The problem is that it doesn't close opened drivers at the end of each test.

Prerequisites: This project is run by Hudson on a Selenium grid server. (I have also run it on my local machine on a Selenium grid server and the problem doesn't occur)

So, I have a BeforeAndAfter class which is implemented by each test class.

Inside BeforeAndAfter I have a @BeforeClass method which starts a new driver: 
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(url), capability);
and a @AfterClass method which does the driver.quit();

Everytime i run the testNG.xml file on the remote Selenium Grid server, it opens a driver for each test class but it leaves it open until the end of the last test when it closes all drivers (all browser windows)

My testNG file looks like this:

```
<parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
<parameter name="url" value="http://10.32.999.99:999/wd/hub"/>


<test name="Regression on test grid">
    <classes>          
        <class name="tests.PageTests.ArticlesPageTest"/>
         <class name="tests.PageTests.CuratorsPageTest"/>
         <class name="tests.FlowTests.NavigateThroughFindings"/>
        <class name="tests.PageTests.DiffToolTest"/>
        <class name="tests.PageTests.ReportsAdminTest"/>           
    </classes>
</test>
```

Any thoughts on the problem ?

PS: In fact, the problem is that the @AfterClass method is not closing the driver after each test class releasing the memory.

Comment: Are you running in parallel?

Comment: Hi, No, it is forced to run sequentially.

Comment: And i have observed it is not quitting the driver even if i specify that at the end of the last method of each class....

Comment: Can you share your driver init and teardown code?

Answer (score 1):

in case of testNG you can use @AfterClass (alwaysRun=true).

Also, in our project we have created batch file to kill the processes after any test class complition. like if any IEdriver.exe or firefox.exe is running you force kill it using windows commads.Make sure you do it before next test class begins by calling batch in Setup fixture method.

Comment: Nice solution, unfortunately Hudson loads the tests from a Unix machine which doesn't understand the taskkill command. Although the tests are run on a Windows machine.(unix machine connects to the grid server and then the tests are run on a windows node) And I don't know if it possible to kill a remote process.

Comment: As I said create a batch and copy it to remote machine with test code or jars/package. next is just to call this batch on remote machine in your test code. we use jenkins for our execution so same thing we have implimented.